# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I'm trying to make my **first** attempt with react.js, I donwloaded the sample project [from here](https://gist.github.com/danawoodman/9cfddb1a0c934a35f31a)

And created a scripts.js [like](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-owner-ownee-relationship) so:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super ();
        this.state = {
            text: 'Default text'
        }
    }

    update (e) {
        this.setState ({text: e.target.value});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.update.bind(this)} type="text" />
                <div>{this.state.text}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

But fires this error

[image]

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

BTW, this is how the .html looks ( screenshot because it uses url-shorteners )

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're transpiling, but don't have the relevant bundler (Webpack, Browserify, etc.) installed and/or have the transpiler set up to assume Node-style modules. We'd have to know a lot more about your environment, build files, etc. to be ble to help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @edgaromar90 I linked to the github page already, but you can check all the files here https://gist.github.com/danawoodman/9cfddb1a0c934a35f31a I only changed scripts.js with the question's code

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but if you check at the content, it contains fb.me url's that won't let me include in the question... ( including a screenshot so you can see )

Comment: also, maybe you shouldn't follow 4 yr old tutorials? the answer you were given below is pretty relevant as a starting point these days

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Thanks, very helpful comment

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: So...you replace them with something else. But it's config, build script, etc. details that really matter here, not so much the HTML.

Comment: fair enough - if you want to be a tool about it, good luck fixing it. FWIW in your screenshot, you're using in-browser versions of react and babel and not bundled, you don't have module imports and exports in the env as @T.J.Crowder said.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I see now your edit. I just want to remind you that I know 0 about react and this is my first attempt. As the wiki of the project says. I just did an `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: visit create-react-app as suggested, fastest way to get going these days w/o having to learn about webpack etc in a modern way. once you get comfortable, `npm run eject`  and configure extra loaders / processors etc but it's fine for the 90th percentile. web dev these days does not use linked static files and hard reloads, it's all streamlined, transpiled, bundled, hot module replacement etc.

Comment: Suggest [starting here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html). It takes you through a step-by-step learning process, either on CodePen or locally using Node and `create-react-app`. There are a lot of moving pieces (transpiling, bundling, etc.), it's easy to get lost amongst them. A lot of that has been automated out of your way to start with by things like `create-react-app`. (You need to understand the pieces *eventually*, but things like that let you build up that knowledge gradually.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain about this, but it looks like you are using ECMA6/7 features in an environment that does not support them.

For a quick and easy project setup, that supports ECMA6/7 you can use [create-react-app package](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)